# Janrain social login UI issue

Tags: joomla, janrain

I have issue Janrain social login UI. I have used two column layout but it renders one column layout.
[image: It should look like][image: but It is look as]
It should look like  image 1

but it is looking like as image 2
Please suggest

Comment: Seem that inherit wrong width size from your css. Without a code snippet of your code it would be hard to find the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i found the issue. There was no issue with janrain. It was mine template css that was conflicting with the css of jainrain.
i am happy that i managed to fix it